# Can't do findViewById

Tags: android, xml, layout

I'm working on a ViewFlipper project. In this main.xml file I have created a webview but I can't reach it in my mainActivity (by findViewById). I can connect the buttons but it just seems like I can't connect with the webview.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/previous"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="previous" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/next"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="next" />
</LinearLayout>

<ViewFlipper
    android:id="@+id/flipper"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#C0C0C0"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />


    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#A0A0A0"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >



        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ViewFlipper>

</LinearLayout>
```

This is a picture of how it looks, And as you can see, i cant reach the webview only the buttons + flipper!

http://postimage.org/image/h3g6yr7r9/

Thanks!

Comment: please post your java code also.  there is nothing wrong with the xml. webView1 id's should be accessible.  please discribe also what exactly "can't connect" mean?

Comment: @user1469324 As your code look alright. Most of the time the project clean should work for this type of issues. Its almost the same but try to give complete path to check if it works like this com.exercise.AndroidViewFlipper.R.id.webView1

Comment: Thanks for the tip, unfortunately nothing new happends when I add the package name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems you are using it the right way,
but I think I know why it does't show on the auto complete suggestions box:
perform a "clean" + "build" operation from eclipse menu tools:

check the

> Project -> Build Automatically

and then hit the:

> Project->Clean

I'm sure after the project re-built, the id of the webView1 would show in the auto complete box.

Comment: If this doesn't work then sometimes just restarting Eclipse should fix it.

Comment: Haha, i have cleaned the project many times without results, strange enough it worked now! Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

See the docs [here.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html)

initialize the webview like this:

`WebView webview = new WebView(this);`

`setContentView(webview);`

Comment: That's what i tried!
No, no errors. Im wondering if it's because it's inside a ViewFlipper?
I don't know, quite a beginner at this!

Comment: Here try my edited answer, I think you initialize it differently

Comment: This'll make the web view full screen though, the other elements won't be shown.

Comment: @muzicmike: please don't confuse the author of the question with this bad advice: instantiation of views inside the java code is bad approch (unless there is a good special reason doing so), and anyway it can't be use that way with the "setContentView" method if you'd like your activity to show anything else beside the webView. it's written also on the link to android developers site you provides